# How can I push locally compiled .LESS .CSS files to the remote server?

Tags: css, ftp, less

I work in a team environment where we keep an up-to-date version of development websites on a remote server. Up to now we have developed CSS conventionally and pushed files to the server using Netbeans.

I have started using LESS and compile using the LESS.app (on OS X) which is fine when developing on a Localhost. I would like to be able to push the files, once compiled, to our remote development server on Save so that other team members can work on an up to date version of the site. Can anyone suggest a way of doing this without having to use a JS compiler or upload manually using FTP?

Comment: Don't the other team members be able to edit the .LESS files?

Comment: Yes they will edit the LESS files too. Even with SVN I would have to compile and then commit. I am looking for a way to compile and then push to the remote server automatically. Somehow watch the folder then push any changes?

Comment: If you are developing with PHP, you can use a less compiler/cacher written in PHP and you don't need to do a watch on any files. https://github.com/leafo/lessphp

Answer (score 2):

This sounds more like a workflow problem than a programming problem, so I'm not sure it belongs on this site, but I can still try to help. I don't think you explained your deployment method adequately, but I can take a stab at it.

The problem comes down to where you compile your source code. There are a few variations on the same three methods:

**Compile at Design Time** - This is your standard command-line compiler like `lessc`, but also includes options such as Air-based desktop applications like LessParser or Less.app on the Mac. There is a growing handful of these types of applications.

**Compile at Compile/Deployment Time** - If you have a build step where you run an Ant or Maven build, a lot of this work has been done thanks to projects like [Asual's LESS CSS Jar](https://github.com/asual/lesscss-engine) and the official  [LESS-Rhino js](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/tree/master/dist) file that is not updated often enough. It's harder to make it happen outside of Java, but it may be doable with [DotLessCSS](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) (.NET), or some other method.

**Compile at Runtime** - Almost no matter your software stack, you can find a LESS compiler that will tie in with your application or your web server. DotLess will tie into IIS. You can use the Java compiler with any Java, Grails or ColdFusion application. There's a PHP compiler. Obviously there's the old Ruby compiler. The LESS.js file will run on Node.JS. Finally, you can use the browser-based Less.js, which probably wouldn't work for everyone.

Don't forget, you can do some kind of combination, so in your development environment you can use the browser-based js compiler, then when you promote it to test or production, you may have it compile at release time and only expose the compiled css file to the public. This way, in development, everyone gets the *.less files (compiled live in the browser), and in production, everyone gets the *.css file.

Comment: Currently we have no strict deployment policy. We have a remote VPS server where we host our PHP/HTML/CSS/JS sites. We use Netbeans IDE, download the file we want to work on, make modifications and put it back with FTP (using Netbeans).

I tried less.js, but found it was not ideal. The Less.app is working fine for me just now, but finding a way for the whole team to be able to compile locally is proving difficult. I think it's time to look at a better development/deploymant workflow.